# Writing the findWinner() for a tictactoe game

Tags: java

I am writing a tictactoe game and I am stuck in writing the findWinner().  The following is what I have but it does not do anything when a player wins any diagonal.

I am using `access1` and `access2` to evaluate whether all the members of the array are equal or not.  Since the loop happens 2 times, if they equal 2, then I return `true`. Thank you

```
public static boolean diagonalTest()
{
  /*create a TicTacToe object to access private fields*/
  TicTacToe temp = new TicTacToe();


  /*an ArrayList to store the values*/
  ArrayList<Character> major = new ArrayList<Character>();

  int k = 0;
  while(k < temp.getRow())
  {
     major.add(temp.getBoard()[k][k]);
     k++;
  }   

  /*to test whether the values in the array are equal to each other*/
  int access1 = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < major.size(); i++)
     if(major.get(0) != ' ' && major.get(0) == major.get(i))
        access1++;

  ArrayList<Character> minor = new ArrayList<Character>();

  k = 0;
  while(k < temp.getRow())
  {
     minor.add(temp.getBoard()[k][temp.getColumn() - 1 - k]);
     k++;      
  }

  int access2 = 0;
  for(int a = 1; a < minor.size(); a++)
     if(minor.get(0) != ' ' && minor.get(0) == minor.get(a))
        access2++;

  if(access1 == 2 || access2 == 2)
     return true;      

 return false;

}
```

Comment: `temp` is never being filled. Also, why is your method so long? Testing a diagonal should be `board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2]` and again, slightly modified for the other diagonal...

Comment: I tried that but I get illegal start of expression.

Comment: public static boolean diagonalTest()
   {
      
      char c = game.getBoard()[0][0];
      char c1 = game.getBoard()[1][1];
      char c2 = game.getBoard()[2][2];
      return (checkDiagonal(c,c1,c2));
         
        
   }

Comment: checkDiagonal just checks whether the characters are equal to each other

Comment: That's a better solution. If it isn't working you should post it in your question, not in the comments.